GCP Cloud Composer Error While Deploying Using Terraform
I am trying to deploy cloud composer using terraform, however it is failing with error.
Error: Error waiting to create Environment: Error waiting for Creating Environment: Error code 9, message: Rerunning Task. Docker image for Composer Agent could not have been pulled. Please check your firewall settings.: Docker image for Composer Agent could not have been pulled. Please check your firewall settings.

This is the env details.
  cloudComposerDtls :
  env1 :
    name: "composer-dev"
    image_version: "composer-2.8.0-airflow-2.6.3"
    scheduler_cpu: 2
    scheduler_memory_gb: 7.5
    scheduler_storage_gb: 5
    scheduler_count: 2
    web_server_cpu: 2
    web_server_memory_gb: 7.5
    web_server_storage_gb: 5 
    worker_cpu: 2
    worker_memory_gb: 7.5
    worker_storage_gb: 5
    worker_min_count: 2
    worker_max_count: 6 
    environment_size: "ENVIRONMENT_SIZE_MEDIUM"
    network: "xxx"
    subnetwork: "xxx"
    composer_service_account: "xxx"
    cluster_secondary_range_name: "pods"
    services_secondary_range_name: "services"
    environment_variables:
      config_bucket: "xxx"
      REGION: "us-east4"
      execution_environment: "DEV"

What firewall rule should I check if it is failing due to firewall issue?
